# Searching for multiple minimums in a dictionary of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, min

I have a dictionary of 2-element-tuples as values:

```
d = {key0:(x0,y0), key1:(x1,y1),...,keyn:(xn,yn)}
```

How may I find the key with the smallest x value? If there were repeated x values, I need the key which tuple has the smallest y value.

Example 1:

```
INPUT: d = {key1:(3,9), key2:(2,5), key3:(8,1)}
OUTPUT: key2
```

Example 2:

```
INPUT: d = {key1:(3,9), key2:(2,5), key3:(8,1), key4:(2,1)}
OUTPUT: key4
```

Answer (score 4):

In both cases, this would be:

```
min(d, key=d.get)
```